# Missing functionalities when deploying Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, printing, about-box

I have created a deploy folder for my Qt gui application, I have added all DLLs it screamed for. The app is running, but there 2 functionalities that are missing.

```
void MainWindow::on_action_About_triggered()
{
    QString filePatch = QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/changelog.txt";
    QFile f(filePatch);
    if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        return;

    QTextStream in(&f);
    QMessageBox::about(this, tr("About testapp"),
                getAppVersion() + "\ntestapp\n\n" + in.readAll());
}
```

And

```
QPrinter printer;
    printer.setFullPage(true);
    printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);

    if (SpecialTypes::printType_t::ePrint == pType)
    {
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);

        QPrintDialog printDial(&printer, this);
        if (printDial.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
        {
            textEdit->document()->print(&printer);
        }
    }
```

Both dialogs are not showing on a computer with the deploy folder. When I run this in Qt creator on the pc I am building the app on, those dialogs work properly. I guess I need to include some additional libraries, but I have no idea which ones, as the app doesn't throw any error, it just doesn't show the dialogs.

Comment: I have solved the problem regarding print dialog- I had to add a folder named printsupport next to the executable. In that folder i had to put windowsprintersupport.dll. I have no idea however why isnt the about dialog working.

Comment: Try to deploy your application using The Windows Deployment Tool which could be found in `QTDIR/bin/windeployqt.exe`. It automatically puts all necessary files in your application directory.

Comment: This program doesnt add some .dll's I need, for example libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems have nothing to do with libraries.

The first method, obviously, returns here:

```
if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    return;
```

The second one doesn't get inside of

```
if (SpecialTypes::printType_t::ePrint == pType)
```

With the first one I'd recommend you to print to log the file name, and, if this is the case, change code to this:

```
QDir dir(QApplication::applicationDirPath());
QFile f(dir.absoluteFilePath("changelog.txt"));
```

If the problem isn't connected to the file path, then you should check file's permissions. And write something like this:

```
if (!f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
    qDebug() << "Error opening file. Error code =" << f.error();
    return;
}
```

For the second one you should definitely add:

```
} else {
    qDebug() << "SpecialTypes::printType_t::ePrint != pType";
}
```

Unfortunatelly, you haven't provided enough data on the second error, and I can't tell the real reason for it.

Comment: Hello, The first case was indeed a problem not connected with libs. The file was indeed not there, thank you. A for the second one, I have been missing windowsprintsupport.dll

Comment: Yes, I read you comment. My mistake :) Desided not to fix this.